# Check if matrix index exists

Tags: python, matrix, indexing, cell, exists

How can I confirm that index exists for a given matrix?

For example:

```
matrix = [[1,2,3],[2,3,4][5,6,7]]

matrix[1][2]
4
```

However, if I do matrix[3][3] I will get an error.

I know I can do:

```
try:
  array[idx]
except IndexError:
```

But what if `idx` is -1? The index does not exist, But in python -1 gives back the index 0.
How do I check for that?

Thank you.

Comment: Why will `-1` give you an error? `matrix[-1][-1]` gives me `7` here, .

Comment: Yes but I want -1 is an index in the matrix .. ( I know it represent the 0 index..)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

```
try:
    if idx1 < 0 or idx2 < 0: raise IndexError()
    array[idx1][idx2]
except IndexError:
    # do stuff
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def dictify(mat):
    return {
        (i, j): cell
        for i, row in enumerate(mat)
        for j, cell in enumerate(row)
    }

matrix = dictify([[1,2,3],[2,3,4], [5,6,7]])

assert (3, 3) not in matrix
assert (1, 0) in matrix

print matrix[1, 1]
```